# How to use array on UITextField?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

How can I use an `NSMutableArray`  on a `UITextField`? I have a button that, when clicked, shows the `UITextField`. I want that every time I press the button a new `UITextField` will be displayed. But I don't know how to use an array.

Comment: What is stored inside the array? And do you want a new text field on every press?

Comment: the one i want to stored in the array is textfield. so that everytime i pressed that button, it will create a new textfield :)

Answer (score 0):

declare an `int counter;` in .h file.

Then, in btn Press event

```
- (IBAction) btnPressed : (id) sender
{
    if(counter < [yourMutableArray count])
    {
        UITextField* myTextFIeld// initializing and all other stuff you want

        //at the end
        counter++;
    }
}
```

This might work, although being more descriptive would help!

Comment: the array is not being called. I really need this.

Comment: what exactly do you need? Be more descriptive

Comment: when a button is click, a UitextField will be created. like this picture. imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/screenshot20121024at754.png